# Can you identify this spider? [UK]

Tags: identification, pest-control, pests

I was clearing out some of my tyre plants. ( A plant literally in a tyre.) and came across this lovely specimin who was on my hand.

I'm absolutely petrified of spiders but I have never seen one like this in the UK. I have shown to others and nobody has been able to identify her thus far.

For scale, front leg to back leg she's around 10cm long. Which I believe is rather large for the UK. The only thing I have come across that has been roughly the same size is the giant house spider but I've never seen one with such a brightly coloured abdomen.

There are videos that you can see of her [here](https://sta.sh/22ba1kkb6f0n?edit=1)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been three years but I can confirm this is a [giant house spider](https://www.wildlifetrusts.org/wildlife-explorer/invertebrates/spiders/giant-house-spider) with a very striking and gorgeous abdomen pattern.

If anyone was wondering I'm still terrified of spiders and think back to this incident regularly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for updating us!  I still regularly think back to the wild tarantula I met years ago.  Handsome, terrifying thing.